# How to create a document template from the plugin in Shopware 5?

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware5

I am trying to create a document through my plugin, the document is inside `MyPlugin/Resources/views/documents/index_foo.tpl` and i have
registered the template by subscribing to event `Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure`

Also added the template directory `$this->template->addTemplateDir($this->pluginDir . '/Resources/views/');`
and its entry in the table `s_core_documents`  but when i try to preview it by going to `Basic Settings > PDF Document Creation > Preview`

i get this error

> Ups! Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten! Wir wurden bereits über das Problem > informiert und arbeiten an einer Lösung, bitte versuchen Sie es in > Kürze erneut.

---

But when i place the template inside `themes/Bare/documents` it works.

Any idea how can i achieve this with my own plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After asking it in the Shopware community Shyim said that the event subscribed is too late for this, Instead use the event mentioned here

https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/event-list/#theme_inheritance_template_directories_collected

After using the event our `Subscriber/TemplateRegistration.php` looked like this

```
class TemplateRegistration implements SubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Enlight_Template_Manager
     */
    private $template;
    private $pluginDir;
    /**
     * TemplateRegistration constructor.
     * @param Enlight_Template_Manager $template
     * @param $pluginDir
     */
    public function __construct(Enlight_Template_Manager $template, $pluginDir)
    {
        $this->template = $template;
        $this->pluginDir = $pluginDir;
    }
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'Theme_Inheritance_Template_Directories_Collected' => 'onCollectTemplateDirectories',
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @param \Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args
     */
    public function onCollectTemplateDirectories(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->template->addTemplateDir($this->pluginDir . '/Resources/views/');
    }
}
```

But even doing so i still faced the error stating

```
Ups! Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten!
Die nachfolgenden Hinweise sollten Ihnen weiterhelfen.

Unable to load template snippet 'documents/index_foo.tpl' in engine/Library/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 127
Stack trace:
#0 engine/Shopware/Components/Document.php(273): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('documents/index...', NULL)
#1 engine/Shopware/Controllers/Backend/Document.php(68): Shopware_Components_Document->render()
#2 engine/Library/Enlight/Controller/Action.php(182): Shopware_Controllers_Backend_Document->indexAction()
#3 engine/Library/Enlight/Controller/Dispatcher/Default.php(478): Enlight_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#4 engine/Library/Enlight/Controller/Front.php(228): Enlight_Controller_Dispatcher_Default->dispatch(Object(Enlight_Controller_Request_RequestHttp), Object(Enlight_Controller_Response_ResponseHttp))
#5 engine/Shopware/Kernel.php(191): Enlight_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#6 vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpCache/SubRequestHandler.php(85): Shopware\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#7 vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php(477): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\SubRequestHandler::handle(Object(Shopware\Kernel), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#8 engine/Shopware/Components/HttpCache/AppCache.php(261): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\HttpCache->forward(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), true, NULL)
#9 vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php(267): Shopware\Components\HttpCache\AppCache->forward(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), true)
#10 engine/Shopware/Components/HttpCache/AppCache.php(102): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\HttpCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), true)
#11 shopware.php(122): Shopware\Components\HttpCache\AppCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#12 {main}
```

The error above got resolved after i adjusted the return of the event in the method `onCollectTemplateDirectories()` in my `Subscriber/TemplateRegistration.php`

Now it looks like this after adjusting

```
class TemplateRegistration implements SubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Enlight_Template_Manager
     */
    private $template;
    private $pluginDir;

    /**
     * TemplateRegistration constructor.
     * @param Enlight_Template_Manager $template
     * @param $pluginDir
     */
    public function __construct(Enlight_Template_Manager $template, $pluginDir)
    {
        $this->template = $template;
        $this->pluginDir = $pluginDir;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'Theme_Inheritance_Template_Directories_Collected' => 'onCollectTemplateDirectories',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param \Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args
     */
    public function onCollectTemplateDirectories(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
    {
        // commented the line below
        // $this->template->addTemplateDir($this->pluginDir . '/Resources/views/');

        // and used this one instead
        $dirs = $args->getReturn();
        $dirs[] = $this->pluginDir . '/Resources/views';
        $args->setReturn($dirs);
    }
}
```

The technical reason behind this was explained by Telgi in the community that

> you have to use the one or the other depending on the event you are
> subscribing to. you need the adjust the return of the event. if you
> subscribe to another event, you need the template service

And now finally when i press the preview button of the template `Basic Settings > PDF Document Creation > Preview` i see the content/text whatever written in the template and no more errors.

Hope this helps someone in the future.